# How to control state of dynamic components with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How can I control the state of components that get added dynamically using `Redux`? I'm able to do it when controlling state with `React`, but when I introduced `Redux`, every component has the same state.

In the example below, click the button to add a parent. Then click the button to add a new child. When clicking the add new parent button again, the second parent has the same number of children as the first. Is it possible to manage each parent state separately, knowing that there can be any number of parents, or should I stick with controlling the state with `React`?

The next step would be to then print the text in all of the children with the print child info button for each parent, but since the state of the children is controlled in a similar manner to the parents, I think that'll be easy once I get over the first hurdle.

Here's the directory structure and code:

```
├── src
│   ├── App.jsx
│   ├── appSlice.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Child.jsx
│   │   ├── Parent.jsx
│   │   ├── childSlice.js
│   │   └── parentSlice.js
│   ├── main.jsx
│   └── store
│       └── store.js
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from './App'
import { store } from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

**App.jsx**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { addParent } from "./appSlice"
import Parent from "./components/Parent";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {parents} = useSelector(state => state.app)

  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'flex', 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      flexDirection: 'column',
      margin: '2rem'
      }}>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addParent())}>Add parent</button>
      <br />
      {parents.map((item) => (
        <Parent key={item}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**appSlice.js**

```
import { v4 as uuid} from "uuid"
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState: {
    parents: []
  },
  reducers: {
    addParent: (state) => {
      state.parents = [...state.parents, uuid()];
    },
  },
});

export const { addParent } = appSlice.actions;

export default appSlice.reducer;
```

**store/store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import appReducer from "../appSlice";
import parentReducer from "../components/parentSlice";
import childReducer from "../components/childSlice"

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    app: appReducer,
    parent: parentReducer,
    child: childReducer
  },
});
```

**components/Parent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Child from './Child'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { addChild } from "./parentSlice"

export default function Parent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const {children} = useSelector(state => state.parent)

  return (
    <div style={{
      width: "100%",
      height: "100px",
      border: "1px solid black",
      marginBottom: "10px",
    }}>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addChild())}>Add new child</button>
      {children.map(item => (
        <Child key={item} />
      ))}
      <button>Print child info</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**components/parentSlice.js**

```
import { v4 as uuid} from "uuid"
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const parentSlice = createSlice({
  name: "parent",
  initialState: {
    children: []
  },
  reducers: {
    addChild: (state) => {
      state.children = [...state.children, uuid()];
    },
  },
});

export const { addChild } = parentSlice.actions;

export default parentSlice.reducer;
```

**components/Child.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { updateText } from './childSlice';

export default function Child() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type='text' 
        onChange={(event) => dispatch(updateText(event.target.value))}
      ></input>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**components/childSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const childSlice = createSlice({
  name: "child",
  initialState: {
    text: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    updateText: (state, {payload}) => {
      state.text = payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateText } = childSlice.actions;

export default childSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, the UI is a function of state and props. In this case, the state is your Redux store. Basically what's missing from your code is the association of child id values to *some* parent id value. All the children are using the same single `state.child` state value, nothing to differentiate them at all.

I suggest the following state slice changes:

### Update the State

`appSlice` - Nothing to change here, this remains the array of parent "node" ids.

```js
const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState: {
    parents: []
  },
  reducers: {
    addParent: (state) => {
      state.parents = [...state.parents, uuid()];
    }
  }
});
```

`parentSlice` - Here you want the state to be an object where the generated parent ids are the keys and the values are arrays of children id values.

```js
const parentSlice = createSlice({
  name: "parent",
  initialState: {
    children: {}
  },
  reducers: {
    addChild: (state, action) => {
      if (!state.children[action.payload]) {
        state.children[action.payload] = [];
      }
      state.children[action.payload].push(uuid());
    }
  }
});
```

`childSlice` - Similarly the child state will be an object where the keys are the child id values and the values are the input value.

```js
const childSlice = createSlice({
  name: "child",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    updateText: (state, action) => {
      state[action.payload.id] = action.payload.value;
    }
  }
});
```

### Rendering the UI from State

`App` - Select `state.app.parents` (*or `Object.keys(state.parent)`!*) and map this array to the `Parent` component and pass the id as a prop.

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { parents } = useSelector((state) => state.app);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
        margin: "2rem"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addParent())}>Add parent</button>
      <br />
      {parents.map((id) => (
        <Parent key={id} id={id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Parent` - Similarly, take the passed `id` prop and select `state.parent.children[id]` to get ***this*** parent's array of children id values. Map these to `Children` component and again pass the child's id value as a prop. `Parent` will pass its `id` value to the dispatched `addChild` action so the reducer knows which parent to add a child to.

```
export default function Parent({ id }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const children = useSelector((state) => state.parent.children[id]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100px",
        border: "1px solid black",
        marginBottom: "10px"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addChild(id))}>Add new child</button>
      {children?.map((childId) => (
        <Child key={childId} id={childId} />
      ))}
      <button>Print child info</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Child` - The child component will select its value via `state.child[id]` using the passed `id` prop and render its input. `Child` will pass its `id` value ***and*** the input value to the dispatched `updateText` action so the reducer function knows which child id is being updated.

```
export default function Child({ id }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const value = useSelector((state) => state.child[id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(event) =>
          dispatch(updateText({ id, value: event.target.value }))
        }
        value={value || ""}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-control-state-of-dynamic-components-with-react-and-redux]

Comment: Thanks for the help! With this approach, in order for my to print all of the child text for a given parent, I had to get the child state in ``Parent``, then pass it to a reducer in ``parentSlice`` in order to be able to find the children that correspond to a given parent. It works, but does that seem like the correct approach? I couldn't figure out how to access the child state in the ``parentSlice``. Here's a fork of the your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-control-state-of-dynamic-components-with-react-and-redux-forked-v7xf3s?file=/src/components/Parent.jsx) with my updates.

Comment: @Simon1 Are you saying for a given parent node, you want to print all that node's children nodes' data? I think what you describe makes sense. Honestly, my initial gut reaction was to suggest placing all the parent/child data in a single slice since they are so heavily coupled. I'm on a work VPN at the moment but will check your sandbox when I've a chance.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. As I was figuring out how to do that print all of the child data for a given parent node, I was also thinking it would probably be easier to combine the parent/child data in a single slice. I originally wanted to keep them separate because there will be a lot more than just ``value`` for the children.

Comment: @Simon1 FWIW having a single state slice with this basic form is not bad IMO: `{ parents: { [parentId]: { children: { [childId]: { value, /* any other children properties */ } } } }`. The basic gist is that the app state should generally be broken up into "chunks" of related data, and here clearly there's a relationship between parents and children, and the children data.

Comment: @Simon1 Having them split as you've done initially though also makes sense though, they are *technically* separate "states". You could create selector functions to read the parts of state and return the parent-children state instead.

Comment: Ok. I'll play around and see which one is easier to understand once the states get more complicated. I appreciate your help. Thank you!